# 特定のディレクトリの下に新しくファイルを作る方法がわからない

Tags: unix

`~/doc`というディレクトリの下に`file.txt`という名前のファイルを作るやり方を教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

コマンドライン（シェル）から操作するということなら

- ディレクトリを作るコマンドは `mkdir`
- ファイルを作るコマンドは `touch` (や任意のエディタ)

ログイン直後はホームディレクトリ `~` にいるはずなので

```
$ mkdir doc
$ touch doc/file.txt # ０バイトのファイルが作られる
$ vi doc/file.txt # エディタを起動し任意の内容を書き込めます
```

カレントディレクトリを移動してから操作するのもありでしょう

```
$ mkdir doc
$ cd doc
$ vi file.txt
```

`vi` (なり他の任意のエディタ) の操作方法はご自分で調査してください（別質問にしても可）